# How to create update trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, transactions

I am trying to create a trigger that will run when items are entered in the orders table the quantity in the products table is suppose to reduce

```
create or replace trigger quantity_dicr after update of quantity on products for each  row
declare
  quantity float;
  begin 
      select quantity into quantity from products where o_id = :new.o_id;
      set quantity = quantity + :new.quantity ,
      where o_id= :new.o_id;
  end quantity_dicr;
```

tables

```
create table products(
prod_id numeric not null,
prod_name varchar2(50) not null,
quantity numeric not null,
price numeric not null,
constraint prod_id_pk primary key(prod_id)
)
create table orders 
(
prod_id numeric not null,
o_id numeric not null,
quantity numeric not null,
o_sum numeric not null,
constraint fk_products  foreign key (prod_id) references products(prod_id),
constraint orders_pk  primary key (o_id) )
)
```

it  is giving me  these errors

```
Error(4,64): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.O_ID'
Error(5,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(5,11): PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
Error(6,19): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.O_ID'
```

any assistance that can shade light why am having these errors will b helpfull

Comment: In table products don't have field O_ID

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be this one:

```
create or replace trigger quantity_dicr 
   after update of quantity on orders 
   for each row
```

Trigger must be defined on table orders instead of table products.

BTW, what happens if a **new** order is placed (i.e. INSERT into orders). This should update the product quantity also, I assume.

Comment: yes the trigger should update both tables, reduce quantity on products

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here

```
create or replace trigger quantity_dicr after update of quantity on products for each  row
declare
  quantity float;
 begin 
  select quantity into quantity from products where o_id = :new.o_id;
  set quantity = quantity + :new.quantity ,
  where o_id= :new.o_id; --Don't have field O_ID in table products
end quantity_dicr;
```

You can do this way.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER quantity_dicr AFTER UPDATE ON orders FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE products SET quantity = quantity - :NEW.quantity WHERE prod_id = :NEW.prod_id;
END quantity_dicr;
```

Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107854/oracle-triggers-update-at-another-table) or the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm) for more information.